# AWK to Split Files

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a below awk command which is looking into "test.sql" file (which has multiple CREATE TABLE statements), I want to generate multiple files based on each CREATE TABLE statement. For which I could achieve with the below command.

But the current file names that are generated is as below :
F1.sql
F2.sql ...

```
awk  '/CREATE TABLE/{x="F"++i".sql";}{print > x;}' test.sql
```

So instead of giving F1.sql or F2.sql, I want to substitute the varaible "F" with some shell holding variable.

**Current OutPut is:**
F1.sql
F2.sql

**Expected Output:**
Declred variable F="test"

Output:
test1.sql
test2.sql

Please suggest.

Comment: @Inian Tried that but was not success full over the above case.

Comment: This is what I treid but no luck:

    awk -v TGT_FILE_NM="${TGT_FILE_NM}" '/CREATE TABLE/{x=TGT_FILE_NM++i".sql";}{print > x;}' test.sql

Answer (score 1):

You are just incorrectly using the `awk` variable that you imported from the shell. It *cannot* be within quotes, under which it is interpreted as a literal string.

```
F="test"
awk -v fname="$F" '/CREATE TABLE/{x=fname""++i".sql";}{print > x;}' test.sql
```

Also you could close the file descriptors opened as part of `print > x` with an explicit `close()` call i.e. as

```
awk -v fname="$F" '/CREATE TABLE/{x=fname""++i".sql";}{print > x; close(x)}' test.sql
```

Comment: So why "" made a differnece @Inian

Comment: @SampatKumar: Notice you had `F` under quotes, it is _incorect_ which is why I didn't have it `""` is just an empty string used to concatenate rest of the string